# Removing Different URLs with Regex

Tags: regex, vim, grep, spam

I am looking to remove a ton of bad spam URL links from my forums using regex in either grep or vim and subsequently using find/replace commands.  I am looking for a way to select just the bad URLs to do that.

All of the URLs are different and are preceeded by `\n________\n`. (Thats 8 underscores)
Here is an example of one of the URLs:

```
\n________\n[URL=http://boxvaporizers.com]Box Vaporizers[/URL]
```

So basically I was trying to use the \n... and the [/URL] as boundaries to select that and everything inbetween. What I came up with is this:

```
[\\]n[_][_][_][_][_][_][_][_][\\]n.*\[\/URL\]]
```

Using that does not correctly close the search and selects pretty much everything. I very am new at this and appreciate any insight. Thanks.

Comment: In `\n\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\n`, are those literally the characters `\n`, or are those newline characters?

Comment: Sorry, posting the correct text proved difficult. It is \n________\n. If that doesnt show either its slash n (8 underscores) slash n and then the URL. Everything about the URL is correct.

Comment: Use backticks for inline code or indent blocks of code with 4 spaces. http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help. Backticks work in comments, blocks don't.

Comment: Ok the post is cleaned up, sorry about that and thanks for the help. Here is an example from the actual bulk of text. `Be well and good luck :D\n________\n[URL=ferrari-wiki.com/wiki/Ferrari_312PB]Ferrari 312Pb Specifications[/URL]'),(5201,'1facba48f9','Proria\'s` I ADVISE NOT VISITNG THE LINK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually able to do this in Microsoft Word using the following:

`[\\]n_{8}[\\]n?*/URL\]`

Thank you for all the input, couldn't have done it without the help!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming [GNU ERE](http://www.regular-expressions.info/gnu.html#ere), this should work:

```
\\n_{8}\\n\s\[URL=(.*)].*\[/URL]
```

RegexBuddy seems to agree with me:

[image: regexbuddy screenshot]

That said,

```
> grep -E \\n_{8}\\n\s\[URL=(.*)].*\[/URL] test.txt
```

doesn't work on my system (Cygwin with GNU grep 2.6.3; `test.txt`'s contents are shown in the screenshot above).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give sed a chance following will do the job:

```
sed 's/^.*\(\[URL.*\)$/\1/' file.txt
```

#### PS: You can do same `:s/^.*\(\[URL.*\)$/\1/` in your vi session as well.

#### OUTPUT

For the file.txt that contains:

\n_***_***\n[URL=http://boxvaporizers.com]Box Vaporizers[/URL]

It produces:

```
[URL=http://boxvaporizers.com]Box Vaporizers[/URL]
```

Answer (score 0):

In Vim this should remove all lines that match the pattern:

```
:g/\\n\%(\\_\)\{8}\\n \[URL=.\{-}\/URL\]/d
```

That pattern matches the sample text taken literally, all in one line.